# Do subclasses with only properties need implementations?

Tags: objective-c, implementation

Earlier today I was wondering, if you make a new subclass which only has properties, IE, a subclass of UITableViewCell that adds a few extra IBOutlets, exposed to the controller through properties, do you really need to have an implementation file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had decided, no, it's not important, and tossed the implementation files out without further thought.

It turns out I was wrong. In my specific case, I ended up with errors like this:

```
Unknown class MyTableViewCell in Interface Builder File
```

It took me a few minutes to track down, until I remembered that I had tossed out my implementation file because I had thought it was useless. lesson learned (and now shared on Stack Overflow): don't do that.

Comment: Even if it wasn't required, I think it would be good practice to keep it, regardless. I view it as the digital equivalent to old manuals that would occasionally say "This page is intentionally blank." It makes the intention clear. If you could delete your empty implementations, it might be frustrating to pick up a project a year later, be hunting for an implementation, and not be entirely sure if the implementation was accidentally deleted or was deliberately not included. Even if it was optional, I'd still be inclined to have a "this page is intentionally blank" implementation.